# MySQL Trying to Return Staggered Results

Tags: mysql, sql, database, search

For example I have a table with three fields:

1. id (int)
2. name (varchar)
3. company (int)

Let's say that I have the following data (example only)

```
id ---    name          ---    company
---------------------------------------
1 ---    John Baker     ---      1
2 ---    Ann Johnson    ---      1
3 ---    John Wu        ---      1
4 ---    Mike Johns     ---      2
5 ---    John John      ---      2
6 ---    Johnny Boy     ---      2
```

I would like perform a search on name, and return the data staggered by company. So if I perform a search on `LIKE '%John%'` , I wish to return the data in a way where it is sorted by company like: 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2 whilst maintaining as much relevancy in return order to the original search term as possible.

I have no idea how to return the data in this staggered way, and I have thought about it for hours. If somebody can please help me I'd love to hear their ideas!

Comment: If you can generate a third column that is "order within company",  so there's company 1:1,2,3, and company 2:1,2,3.. then you order by that column, company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be rather easy if we could use SQL standard functions to ROW_NUMBER each `name` PARTITIONed BY `company`.  (ROW_NUMBER gives us a "naive ranking" or simple numbering, with no ties and no gaps.)  This is essentially @zebediah49's proposal in his comment.  MySQL, sadly, cannot today do this.

[@GordonLindoff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16041708/132382) simulates this functionality in MySQL with a self-join technique.  Here's another way to do the same.

First we group every person by company and then globally naively rank them, using a user variable.  So, the three people in company A become #1, #2, and #3, and the two people in company B become #4 and #5, and so on:

```
company | name     == ROW_NUMBER()d after ==>  company | name    | rank
--------+--------  == GROUP BY `company`  ==>  --------+---------+------
    A   | Alice                                    A   | Alice   | 1
    B   | Bob                                      A   | Charlie | 2
    A   | Charlie                                  A   | Deborah | 3
    A   | Deborah                                  B   | Bob     | 4
    B   | Erwin                                    B   | Erwin   | 5
```

The *user variable* technique to simulate ROW_NUMBER in MySQL is easy to search for, but here's a compact demonstration from [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15986591/132382).

Now if we MOD a global naive rank by the number of people within a company, we get a "partitioned rank", a relative rank within the company:

```
company | name     | rank | npeople | rank % npeople
--------+----------+------+---------+----------------
    A   | Alice    |  1   |  3      | 1
    A   | Charlie  |  2   |  3      | 2
    A   | Deborah  |  3   |  3      | 0
    B   | Bob      |  4   |  2      | 0
    B   | Erwin    |  5   |  2      | 1
```

Putting it all together, JOINing against a query to count the number of people in each company, we get:

```
  SELECT id, name, ranked.company
    FROM (  SELECT tbl.id, tbl.name, tbl.company, (@rn := @rn + 1) AS rn
              FROM tbl
              JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0) vars
             WHERE tbl.name LIKE '%John%'
          ORDER BY company) ranked
    JOIN (SELECT company, COUNT(id) AS npeople FROM tbl GROUP BY company) companies
         ON ranked.company = companies.company
ORDER BY rn MOD companies.npeople, company
```

Comment: Thanks - this is the explanation I understood the most. I tried it first in excel using modulus, and it works exactly how I want it to. I'd vote up but I don't have enough reputation! Thanks to everybody who answered, but for me this answer is the clearest.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it sorted by company:

```
select *
from t
where . . .
order by company, id;
```

If you want it interleaved, then a counter within a company helps.  Here is one way:

```
select t.*
from (select *,
             (select count(*) from t t2 where <where clause on t2 here> and t2.comapny = t.company and t2.id < t.id) as seqnum
      from t
      where . . .
    ) t
order by seqnum, company
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
select *
from yourTable
where ...
order by ((company*1000) + id);
```

Add as much zeros as you need. At least, you'll need as much zeros as this number:

```
select pow(10,length(max(company))) from yourTable;
```

The ordering may be quite slow if you pull a lot of records in this query, so I suggest you use an optimal `where` condition.

Not the most elegant solution, but it may work.